# Indexer, Reindex ALL Magento2

Tags: magento2, indexer

New to Magento2,
I am trying to use the Indexer to reindexAll.

I tried with the objectManager, without success.

Sample :

```
$indexer  = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer');

$ret = $indexer->reindexAll();
```

> [InvalidArgumentException]  view does not exist.

How can I get  this ?
Any tips, or docs will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found code this code in my improved reindex module: https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/improved-asynchronous-reindex.html

```
$indexerIds = [<ids>];
$indexRegistry = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry');
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    $indexer = $indexRegistry->get($indexerId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
```

Comment: cataloginventory_stock
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_rule
catalogsearch_fulltext
catalog_category_product
catalog_product_attribute
catalog_product_category
catalog_product_price
customer_grid
design_config_grid